# InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Cookies",...)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im getting this error message when logging in using my ASP.NET application as admin user.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
proyectoFinal.Controllers.AccountController.Login(string username, string password) in AccountController.cs
```

```
                };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            // Authentication failed
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid credentials");
```

It does highlight this line:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

---

This is my **AccountController.cs**:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") 
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ///////////////// Authentication failed
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid credentials");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Project
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                });

            //////////////////////////////////////////// Configure authorization
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireRole("Admin");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("ManagerOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireRole("Manager");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireRole("User");
                });
            });

            // Add other services and dependencies
            services.AddMvc();
        }



        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication(); // Place UseAuthentication before UseAuthorization
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

---

#EDIT

```
    using Project;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SQLiteDBContext>(); // SQLiteDBContext

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<SQLiteDBContext>();
    dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}

// Run the application
app.Run();
```

Tried so many times wihout success

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you using? (It looks like you're using ASP.NET Core 3.x or 5.x, right?). Where is your `Startup` class being used by `IHost`?  Have you verified that your `ConfigureServices` method is actually being called, such as by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Hey @Dai, take a look:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: @Dai how can i verify if the Startup class is neign used by IHost?

Comment: Don't you have a `Program.cs` file?

Comment: @Dai sorry, Dai. I was kinda lost. Take a look, i have edited the question

Comment: Your problem is you're mixing ASP.NET Core 2.x (or 3.x) code with an ASP.NET Core 6 project template. I recommend you start-over with a new project template in VS and _don't copy-and-paste anything over_, instead follow the official guides and documentation specific for ASP.NET Core 6 and you should ignore documentation for 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @Dai Dai, sorry. Could you explain to me how do you get to that conclusion?

Comment: Because your file with `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` is from the ASP.NET Core 6.0 project templates, while your file with `public class Startup` is from the ASP.NET Core 2.x-3.x project templates.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will follow you.. im new to this and i was kinda "playing" with the code.
Please, stay sharp if i tag you later @Dai

Comment: Hi, asp.net core for identity has [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) here. And please follow @Dai 's advice and test again, thanks.

Comment: and if you created a new case with VS, you might [Scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) Identity in ASP.NET Core projects