# fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] Connection id "0HMRQHOSA1VM6", Request id "0HMRQHOSA1VM6:0000000

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Getting this strange ASP.NET Core 6.0 error message after logging as admin:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "0HMRQHOSA1VM6", Request id "0HMRQHOSA1VM6:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Cookies",...)?
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at proyectoFinal.Controllers.AccountController.Login(String username, String password) in C:\Users\source\repos\parc\project\project\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 35
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilterAsync(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, String requestId, HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

---

My STARTUP.CS:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace proyectoFinal
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add authentication services
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            });

            // Configure authorization
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireRole("Admin");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("ManagerOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireRole("Manager");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("UserOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireRole("User");
                });
            });

            // Add other services and dependencies
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }



        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication(); 
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

AccountController.cs

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace proyectoFinal.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // Perform your authentication logic here
            // e.g., validate the username and password against a user store

            // Simulate a successful authentication
            if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") // Assign the "Admin" role
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            // Authentication failed
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid credentials");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using proyectoFinal;

var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<SQLiteDBContext>(); // Register the SQLiteDBContext
        })
        .Configure((hostContext, app) =>
        {
            if (!hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<SQLiteDBContext>();
                dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
               
            }
        });
    });

await builder.RunConsoleAsync();




What am i doing wrong? its annoying!
```

Tried so many times without success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Cookies",...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596791/invalidoperationexception-no-sign-in-authentication-handlers-are-registered-di) You just posted the same thing earlier

Comment: Hey @Charlieface this time the error was not shown in the browser but in the vs console

Comment: I have a same problem when I try to host and run .NET 6 application on Linux (RedHat), when I remove app.UseAuthentication() from program.cs it builds without errors, but I can not imagine how to fix it, I really need app.UseAuthentication() for my app

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates you haven't registed the required handler(as below) for cookie authetication .

```
AddAuthentication().AddCookie(....)
```

I checked your codes,although you've registed CookieAuthentication and the handler  in startup.cs ,but it was never called(Check the codes below,`webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();` is required).

Please doubule click your project,open the .csproj file and check the .net version of your project

[image]

For .net 5 or lower versions

keep your startup.cs,modify your program.cs as below:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

For .net 6 or higher versions,you could try as mentioned above

or try as below in Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// regist the services you registed in ConfigureServices method in startup.cs
builder.Services.Add.....

var app = builder.Build();
// call the middlewares you've called in Configure method in startup.cs
app.Run;
```

If you try with new host model,startup si not required

Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) related,hopes help

Comment: This does not answer the question since the old way still works fine and probably always will. It also doesn't address the actual problem in the question in any way. The new format with writing everything in `Program.cs` is just a more concise way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @ Karl-Johan Sjögren，The the actual problem is that OP registed  the handler in starup.cs ,but he never called webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); so what erver you've configured in starup.cs ,it won't be called

Comment: "Apps migrating to 6.0 don't need to use the new minimal hosting model" it has been mentioned in the document.it's optional

Comment: Then rewrite your answer to focus on that, right now the answer isn't focusing on explaining what the problem is (but now that you mention what the error is in the comment I can see that you are right).